# Parsing JSON to dataframe from CSV file

Tags: r, json, parsing

I was given a CSV file and each cell/row has a different JSON payload response. I am wondering how would I be able to parse the JSON in each cell (apply/loop over) and then create a dataframe where you would have the header and values? I have been trying to use jsonlite and jsonlite's streamin function but have been unsuccessful so far. Below is an example of cells A2 and A3:

```
-- begin A2
{
  "campaign_id": null,
  "campaign_name": null,
  "canvas_id": {
    "string": "bd0905ab-73f3-4581-a013-1db25b11c7a9"
  },
  "canvas_name": {
    "string": "canvas_name"
  },
  "canvas_step_id": {
    "string": "f30facac-511d-4e80-8873-af1b7b1f9164"
  },
  "canvas_step_name": {
    "string": "Email 1"
  },
  "canvas_variation_id": {
    "string": "7740c9db-b6c6-47e5-8d32-7f1038be1f15"
  },
  "canvas_variation_name": {
    "string": "Variant 1"
  },
  "dispatch_id": {
    "string": "62aecfb4dc4b1a4cbcb18a65d4f359d7"
  },
  "email_address": "abc@abc.com",
  "external_user_id": {
    "string": "7519e106-2eb9-5f75-a757-a3e33494e87f"
  },
  "id": "657e5822-5d1a-4659-8215-1bc1b5998fde",
  "ip_pool": {
    "string": "Marketing - mail"
  },
  "message_variation_id": null,
  "send_id": null,
  "time": 1655623606,
  "timezone": null,
  "user_id": "62aecf71e06cf91245f236ec"
} 
-- begin A3
{
  "campaign_id": null,
  "campaign_name": null,
  "canvas_id": {
    "string": "bd0905ab-73f3-4581-a013-1db25b11c7a9"
  },
  "canvas_name": {
    "string": "canvas_name"
  },
  "canvas_step_id": {
    "string": "f30facac-511d-4e80-8873-af1b7b1f9164"
  },
  "canvas_step_name": {
    "string": "Email 1"
  },
  "canvas_variation_id": {
    "string": "7740c9db-b6c6-47e5-8d32-7f1038be1f15"
  },
  "canvas_variation_name": {
    "string": "Variant 1"
  },
  "dispatch_id": {
    "string": "62aeb2dde155d85f0cfd34c8413ed8bc"
  },
  "email_address": "def@def.com",
  "external_user_id": {
    "string": "3e0aa186-d68a-5d99-849e-ab86131ee1fa"
  },
  "id": "ff37284c-8554-4d61-ba8c-987f2e1c40fd",
  "ip_pool": {
    "string": "Marketing - mail"
  },
  "message_variation_id": null,
  "send_id": null,
  "time": 1655616224,
  "timezone": null,
  "user_id": "62aeb298db990a73de316ca7"
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Attempted using this:
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("[\r\n]", "", csv_file)))

But got this error:
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       c("{\n\"campaign_id\":null,\n\"

Comment: I have tried removing new lines and spaces but now get: Error in textConnection(dataframe) : invalid 'text' argument

Answer (score 0):

I think I got an answer here:

```
output <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", csv_file$DATA)))
```

I was having issues because of the column name when I didn't explicitly say "$DATA" after csv_file.